# Spring Boot - How to exclude an imported @Configuration in specific profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

`RestTemplateConfig` is a configuration class with `@Configuration`, It is imported in my project as an dependency, which I cannot remove and also don't have access to edit. So I cannot add anything like `@Profile("!dev")` in it.

The Application with it works well in an docker image running in a k8s cluster. But when I need to run it locally to debug, a bean in this configuration will fail to get created and make the application down.

Appreciate a lot if you can advise how to exclude this configuration class only in "dev" profile!

Comment: Why not just fix the error at startup instead of excluding it? Apparently the configuration is needed somehow. You can always add an `@ComponentScan` with an `excludeFilter` so you can filter out the classes. See https://deinum.biz/2021-11-05-Component-Scanning/ for an extensive look at filtering (include in this case but it works the same for an exclude).

Comment: you can extend the RestTemplateConfig  class and try to override the methods in order to run it locally